AzureML endpoint deployment failed because of permissions
I am trying to deploy an endpoint for my model but kept getting errors related to permissions:
Kind: Pod, Name: DownloadFailed, Type: Warning, Time: 2024-10-31T01:26:40.607179Z, Message: Model download failed, retrying. Please check storage-initializer log for detail.
Here is the storage-initializer log:
[Storage download stage] processing error: error when getting file size: HEAD https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/path/to/model, RESPONSE 403: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. ERROR CODE: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Here are my steps:
1: I created a Model in my workspace
az ml model create --name mymodel --resource-group myrg -w myws --version 1 --path azureml://subscriptions/123-31233-2323-232/resourcegroups/myrg/workspaces/myws/datastores/mydatastore/paths/path/to/my/model/weights

2: create an Environment:
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/environment.schema.json
name: mymodel-env
image: myacr.azurecr.io/image:1
version: 1

3: create an endpoint
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/managedOnlineEndpoint.schema.json
name: mymodel-ep
auth_mode: aad_token

4: then I do the deployment:
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/managedOnlineDeployment.schema.json
name: mymodel-deployment
endpoint_name: mymodel-ep
model: azureml:mymodel:1
code_configuration:
  code: ../src/model/folder
  scoring_script: score.py
environment: azureml:mymodel-env:1
instance_type: my-instance-type
instance_count: 1

I feel it might be a service bug. But anyone please correct me.
Thanks
as describe above.
I would expect the deployment should be able to download the created model.

Could you include what Azure RBAC roles you have under storage account and add Networking settings Portal image of your storage account in your question.

The error occurs when Azure ML service does not have required permissions to access storage account where the model is stored or there might be network connectivity issue.
To resolve the error, make sure to assign proper RBAC roles like "Storage Blob Data Contributor" to service principal or user under your storage account like this:

Check whether your storage account is allowing access to all networks or not by visiting Networking tab:

If your storage account is set to selected virtual networks, ensure that Azure ML workspace is within the same VNet and storage account’s firewall settings allow access from trusted Azure services like Azure ML service:

